# Intermittent ABS indication - 1998 Grand Cherokee

Tags: jeep, abs

I have a 1998 Grand Cherokee. About 3 weeks ago, I had the brake pads and rotors replaced all around to fix a pulsation problem. Nothing else was performed or recommended to me at that time about any other brake servicing (brake fluid flush, line bleed, etc.). Brakes feel perfectly normal now. However, the other day the ABS indicator came on, and stayed on for a couple of engine starts. After sitting a couple of days, I drove the car again today, no ABS indicator for one trip (other than the usual "lights test" on engine start), but came on again during a later trip.

What could account for the intermittent ABS indicator? A wheel sensor failing? Is this an expensive repair?

I had an ABS wheel sensor fail on a 1995 Z28, and had to have the entire wheel bearing replaced (ABS sensor is integrated into it on the GM car) which was an expensive repair. Is the situation similar for the Jeep?

Comment: The ABS module should have a retained fault. Most chain auto part stores will read the code for free. If you can edit your post to include the code or fault  we can give you a better idea of what the repair will involve.